# How to Bypass Admin Area Authentication for Testing

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I want to speed test Magento admin area with some 3rd party tool. However I can't do it as Magento admin area requires authentication.

Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Can you mention that tool?

Comment: Thank you very much Alex, I will test it tomorrow at my working hours.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are doing the tests via a browser-frontend? (Selenium or similar)?

Some thoughts:

### Avoid real passwords in the test scripts

Just create a user "tester" pw: "tester123" or similar before running the tests. This can be automatized, for example using the FOSS tool: [magerun](http://www.magerun.net/)

`n98-magerun.phar admin:user:create tester tester@example.com tester123 Foo Bar`

*full disclosure: I am a contributor of the magerun project*

### Avoid two steps (open /admin, fill and submit form)

Actually - after you did the login once, the session should be kept open (you can also tune the session time outs). So you have to log in only once and can then jump directly to admin.

This works only if your database / sessions are not fully reset for each test.

### Remove to whole login

You could implement a module which simulates the admin session. Have a look at the `EcomDev_PHPUnit` testing framework - [this method](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit/blob/fa55d23d3e2a421a14ea8db6a7b251b81d9334ba/app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/Test/Case/Controller.php#L2014) might be a good start.
(but has to be rewritten if you do not use `EcomDev_PHPUnit`)

Comment: Alex, can I contact you at Skype or Hangouts or other ?

Comment: If it concerned to the question please keep the discussion here. If there are to many comment, it will automatically suggest to chat. Don't worry.